# vscode own devcontainer in dropdown menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I like to have my own devcontainer added in the dropdown menu in vscode beside the predefineds like C++.

I just copied my own `.devcontainer` to `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.0/dist/node_modules/vscode-dev-containers/containers/cpp_kurs` and it perfectly does what I want.

But I guess it is a little bit dirty and will be gone when the extension gets updated at least because the version number in is the folder name.

Is there a clean, good and stable way of doing this (I don't want to fork the plugin and maintain it)?